# Couchbase N1QL: GROUP BY CASE clause not working

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am trying to execute GROUP BY CASE query on the Couchbase workbench.

The query is -

```
SELECT Hemisphere, COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS LandmarkCount
FROM `travel-sample` AS l
WHERE type="landmark"
GROUP BY CASE
  WHEN l.geo.lon <0 THEN "West"
  ELSE "East"
END AS Hemisphere;
```

This query is provided by the Couchbase documentation as an example to execute GROUP BY CASE queries on [this link](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/groupby.html)

I am getting the following error:

```
[
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at AS",
    "query_from_user": "SELECT Hemisphere, COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS LandmarkCount\r\nFROM `travel-sample` AS l\r\nWHERE type=\"landmark\"\r\nGROUP BY CASE\r\n  WHEN l.geo.lon <0 THEN \"West\"\r\n  ELSE \"East\"\r\nEND AS Hemisphere;"
  }
]
```

I am working on Community Edition 6.0.0 build 1693.

Comment: I found out that only documentation of couchbase v6.6 provides this query, but I am using v6.0, but is there any way to execute similar query in v6.0 also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have the solution you want:

```
SELECT Hemisphere,
  COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS LandmarkCount
FROM `travel-sample` AS l
LET Hemisphere = CASE
    WHEN l.geo.lon <0 THEN "West"
    ELSE "East"
  END
WHERE type="landmark"
GROUP BY Hemisphere;
```

The error you're getting is because in 6.0, `AS` isn't supported in `GROUP BY` ([as shown in the 6.0 docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/groupby.html) and as the error message says).

An alternative is to [use `LET` in 6.0+ to define a variable](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/let.html), as I did in the above example.

But note that `LET` is not *required* either; you could also write your query without it, like this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN l.geo.lon <0 THEN "West"
    ELSE "East"
  END AS Hemisphere,
  COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS LandmarkCount
FROM `travel-sample` AS l
WHERE type="landmark"
GROUP BY CASE
  WHEN l.geo.lon <0 THEN "West"
  ELSE "East"
END;
```

But I think you'll agree that the former is easier to read, understand, and change.